# Callback each time subprocess prints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an external program I want to call, for example `ping -t 8.8.8.8`.

And I am a bit confused as to what to do in order to have a callback each time the `ping` prints an output.

I am looking for a way to call a piece of code with the latest output line each time there is an output.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, the trick is using `process.stdout.readline()` since it blocks untill there is a line ready.

Sample code:

```
cmd = "ping -t www.google.com"
ping = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

try:
    while True:
        line = str(ping.stdout.readline(), "ascii")
        print(line)  # this can be anything
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ping.terminate()  # don't wanna leave a process hanging in the background
```